# using vlookup in excel to compare columns

Tags: excel

I have some data with close to 250 rows in a excel sheet(Excel 2003) that needs to be compared. Appreciate if someone can help me with vlookup / any other excel routine that can help me achieve this. How do i filter out failed results ?Some sample data from my excel sheet:

```
Condition to check:
Where $E = $Q
Check if rows ($F - $K) = rows($R to $w) 

Rows ( E - K )
1000xyz400100xyzA00680xyz0  19722.83    19565.7 157.13  11  2.74        11.00
1000xyz400100xyzA00682xyz0  7210.68     4111.53 3099.15 216.95  1.21    216.94
1000xyz430200xyzA00651xyz0  146.70      0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

Rows (Q - W )
1000xyz400100xyzA00680xyz0  19722.83   19565.70 11.00   13.74   2.74    11.00
1000xyz400100xyzA00682xyz0  7210.68    4111.53  216.94  218.15  1.21    216.94
```

Another question is, do I need to perform a sort before I can check this or is vlookup able to handle unsorted data.

Comment: q1: are these ($E:$K) and ($Q:$W) two independent tables contained in the same sheet?

q2: are rows $E and $K the "keys" which uniquely identify each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you end up using vlookup for this as in the example I've given below, then you shouldn't need to sort as the Range_lookup value is set to FALSE which forces VLOOKUP to search for exact matches only, although if there are duplicates in your inital comparison rows E or Q then you could run into trouble with not finding all the instances of the matched data.

The formula below first checks to see if the first condition can be matched and then compares each of the 6 subsequent columns with their counterparts. This particular formula simply returns "Not Found" if no initial match, "All OK" if all rows match with their counterpart, or "Not OK" if one or more do not match. To get information on which field is notequal then you would need to break up the AND function to return column details.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,2,FALSE)),"Not Found",IF(AND(F1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,2,FALSE),G1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,3,FALSE),H1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,4,FALSE),I1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,5,FALSE),J1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,6,FALSE),K1=VLOOKUP(E1,$Q$1:$W$2,7,FALSE)),"All OK","Not OK"))
```

To use it just drop it into a column adjacent to the set of data.

Comment: Thanks Ulkash. Works well for me. The only problem is, I can't identify which are the corresponding elements, where the amounts mis-match, becoz the rows between both the tables are not aligned. any suggestions ?

Comment: If sorting the data is not an issue then sort both ranges.
It's a little fiddly as you need to move the rows that don't have a match in the first column out of the way.
You could actually move the data to another sheet but I'll try to use sort to just put the required data at the top.

Comment: Sort the first range with both the vlookup column descending and then first column (E) ascending.
(It just so happens that with the strings I chose in the vlookup this will put the mismatches at the top, the the rows without
 a corresponding value in the 2nd range and then the rows where the data matches up correctly - as an aside, if you changed Not Found to Absent then the All OK rows will line up as well).

Comment: To sort the 2nd range there are two options, you could use a vlookup to look for rows where there isn't a match in the first row and then sort in the same way as bove or perhaps more simply use the match formula that Mike proposed
=MATCH(E2;$Q:$Q;0) then sort the 2nd range on the result of the match formula.
You can then use autofilter to select the rows as required.

Answer (score 0):

under the assumption of YES to both q1 and q2, I propose you use some (temporary) columns to validate your tables. The example shows what functions you would typically use for that kind of question:

```
column : L
heading: "FoundInQ"
formula: =NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E2;$Q:$Q;1;FALSE)))
purpose: check if key found in E2 is present anywhere in column Q
comment: if Vlookup with the FALSE option doesn'g find an exact match, it returns #NA
         and we make use of that by specifically testing that using ISNA()
         E2 is the only relative address, so safe to copy this down your table

column : M
heading: "WhereInQ"
formula: =MATCH(E2;$Q:$Q;0)
purpose: get number of row in Q where key is found
comment: this we don't need directly, it is to illustrate how you get an index for a
         search key within a target range. Mind the parameter "0" at the end

column:  N
heading: "F equal R"
formula: =F2=INDEX($R:$R;M2)
comment: M2 makes use of the MATCH function above, here split for better clarity
```

Now you have some basic techniques of finding a key, getting an associated value etc. You can combine formulae like inserting the one of column M into the "M2" argument of formula N, let the whole be displayed conditionally on the result of column L, expand column N for more adjacent columns like in

```
=AND(F2=INDEX($R:$R;M2);G2=INDEX($S:$S;M2);H2=INDEX($T:$T;M2);...)
```

Needless to say that you should define an AutoFilter across these (temp) columns to seperate good from bad, and that the whole logic (looking from E to Q) can be reversed.

And No the two subtables need not be sorted.

That should solve ....

Good luck MikeD

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for the detailed info. The answer to both your questions is "yes". But when i used your formula, i get an error message saying " the formula u typed contains an error". Also tried " =NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E2;$Q$2:$Q$241;1;FALSE)))", still the same. any suggestions ?

Comment: I am using German locale settings on my PC, you may need to replace the ";" by "," within the formule. If this is not the reason, come back once more. Good luck MikeD